# Random replacement of a particular character in file (ruby)

Tags: ruby, gsub

I tried to find a simple solution to replace a particular character randomly within a file.

Unfortunately, my solution replaces all found characters and not just some of them.

```
file_names = ['users_controller.rb']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(",", ";") #replaces , to ; (unfortunatly all and not just some)
  puts new_contents
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to replace some random occurrences of a particular (fixed) character with a particular (fixed) character?

Comment: yes ( as example the character occurs 12 times in the file but only a random amount of them gets replaced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. If you want to replace some random occurrences of a particular (fixed) character (`","`) with a particular (fixed) character (`";"`), then do:

```
text.gsub(","){rand(2).zero? ? "," : ";"}
```

Comment: Thank You sawa that  perfectly fits my question

Comment: A more flexible way to easily define the probability would be: `(rand < 0.5) ? "," : ";"` -- as you can now define arbitrary percentages, rather than being limited to saying "1 in X".

Comment: @tom lord...does `(rand < 0.5) ? "," : ";"` its a 50-50 chance of replacement so if i do `(rand < 0.3) ? "," : ";"` its a 30-70 chance of replacement?

Comment: Yes - A 30% chance of being "," and a 70% chance of being ";"